# How to serialize Ecto record struct to make it storeable as :map in the database?

Tags: elixir, ecto

I want to store an `Ecto.Schema` struct which is returned from `Repo.get(MyModel, id)`.

Stuff like `__meta__`, `association: <Association is not loaded>` prevents from jsonifying it, so I catch an exception (it's reasonable). Is there any `Ecto` native function to get only map of record columns which I can serialize & store at the database?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My solution

```
defmodule MyApp.Schema do
  @schema_meta_fields [:__meta__]

  def to_storeable_map(struct) do
    association_fields = struct.__struct__.__schema__(:associations)
    waste_fields = association_fields ++ @schema_meta_fields

    struct |> Map.from_struct |> Map.drop(waste_fields)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Since I don't know any Ecto native function for this purpose, I guess you should use:

https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#from_struct/1

Filter the keys you don't want with:

https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#filter/2

And set the result with:

https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#into/2

**Edit**: It looks like you can use "map()" in your queries to return a map than a struct: https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/issues/1348

Answer (score 0):

Elixir allows you to *derive* a protocol implementation: [Kernel.defstruct/1](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#defstruct/1-deriving)

I'm not sure what JSON parser you are using but with `Jason`, for example, you can find the following in their README:

```
If you need to encode some struct that does not implement the protocol, if you own the struct, you can derive the implementation specifying which fields should be encoded to JSON:

@derive {Jason.Encoder, only: [....]}
defstruct # ...

Finally, if you don't own the struct you want to encode to JSON, you may use Protocol.derive/3 placed outside of any module:

Protocol.derive(Jason.Encoder, NameOfTheStruct, only: [...])
Protocol.derive(Jason.Encoder, NameOfTheStruct)
```

Might as well show how to do it with Poison as well:

```
When deriving structs for encoding, it is possible to select or exclude specific attributes. This is achieved by deriving Poison.Encoder with the :only or :except options set:

defmodule PersonOnlyName do
  @derive {Poison.Encoder, only: [:name]}
  defstruct [:name, :age]
end

defmodule PersonWithoutName do
  @derive {Poison.Encoder, except: [:name]}
  defstruct [:name, :age]
end
In case both :only and :except keys are defined, the :except option is ignored.
```